# Pi 4 is not booting anymore

Tags: boot, 22.04, raspberrypi

I am a total noob in pi and ubuntu.
My PI4 with 22.04 worked fine. Today it wont turn on anymore. Just get the message "zswap zpool z3fold not available, using default zbud" before screen turns off. The SD card booted on a PI3 but it was to slow to work with. Hope you can help :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SklNs.jpg)

Comment: RaspberryPI is Debian, Bullseye is the version for the PI4.  Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't run on PI as far as I know.

Comment: @Mike then you would be wrong because I have several Pis running 22.04.

Comment: @ThomasWard - I stand corrected.  I've only ever used the OS from the official PI site (Bullseye and Buster).